# React JS - Get data from row in rendered table to edit data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a way the admon can edit stored data in ParseServer.

I implemented a way to search records, filter data and re-render again. Now, my need is edit the fetched data and update the record via UPDATE VERB.

[image]
How could get the row data?. For example console.log the the "Código".

This my source code:

```
render() {
    return (
     <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"><center>Edit</center></th>
                                    <th scope="col"><center>#</center></th>
                                    <th scope="col"><center>Código</center></th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nombres</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Grado</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="cursorPointer">
                                   {/*Rendering data*/}
                                    {this.state.data.map(function(item, key) {
                                        return (
                                            <tr key = {key} >
                                                <td><center><button ... > Edit </button></center></td>
                                                <td><center>{item.objectId}</center></td>
                                                <td><center>{item.Codigo}</center></td>
                                                <td>{item.Nombres}</td>
                                                <td>{item.Apellidos}</td>
                                                <td>{item.Grado}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </tbody>
                            </table> 
  )
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: @Matheus Reis solutions works perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a method edit that will receive the `data` of the row, and call it on the button `Edit`:

```
edit = (data) => { 
    // Do whatever you want
}
render() {
    return (
     <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th scope="col"><center>Edit</center></th>
                 <th scope="col"><center>#</center></th>
                 <th scope="col"><center>Código</center></th>
                 <th scope="col">Nombres</th>
                 <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                 <th scope="col">Grado</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody id="cursorPointer">
              {/*Rendering data*/}
              {this.state.data.map( (item, key) => {
                 return (
                      <tr key = {key} >
                      <td>
                        <center>
                           <button onClick={() => this.edit(item)}>Edit<button>
                        </center>
                      </td>
                      <td><center>{item.objectId}</center></td>
                      <td><center>{item.Codigo}</center></td>
                      <td>{item.Nombres}</td>
                      <td>{item.Apellidos}</td>
                      <td>{item.Grado}</td>
                   </tr>
                 )
              })}
        </tbody>
     </table> 
  )
}
```

**PS:** Note that the function of the map needs to be an arrow function, to bind the component to it, then it can access the `edit` method.

Comment: Thanks **Matheus**, I'm testing your idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matheus Reis your solution works like a charm.

Comment: This works thank you, But  I also want to bind data values in another component how can I do this?

Comment: @RohitGautam the other component is in the same level? If so, you just need to pass it as a `prop`. If not, you will need [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Comment: Thanks. But I have console log the data in edit function. All the rows data console log there. but i want that row only.

Comment: @SachinMuthumala that's probably because you're passing the wrong parameter to the function