# How to get a row data from a dynamic table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic `table` in my app and I get its data from an api, I need to get on of its parameters and add some others then post it to another api.

so this is the form-table:
[image]

and here is my `code`:

```
  edit = (data) => { 
    console.log()
}              
  return (
    <div className="App">
      

      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Horse Name(ENG)</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Owner</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Microchip id</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Number</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Round</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {product
              .filter((item) => {
                if (search == []) {
                  return item;
                }
              })
              
              .map((item) => {
                
                return (

                  <TableRow key={item.id}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {item.nameEn}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {item.owner}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {item.chipNumber}
                    </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <TextField label="number" variant="standard" />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <TextField label="Round" variant="standard" />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <Button variant="primary"
                          value={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Publish'}
                          onClick={() => edit(item)}
                          // onClick={handleAdd}
                          disabled={loading}>Add to round</Button>
                      </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>

                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );


}
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass the row data from table to `edit` as a string, I want when I call edit function, it prints the one of the parameters on the row

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156117/react-js-get-data-from-row-in-rendered-table-to-edit-data) helped me a little but I don't know why it doesn't work well and it doesn't recognize `data` as a `function`. I am really a newbie sorry if it has an obvious problem!

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.  The data populating the table is in the variable `product` (which really should be pluralized, names matter).  And the button in each table row passes the `item` for that row to the `edit` function.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: thanks ill make it better, the problem is it doesn't pass the `item` to `edit`. it's like it doesn't find `edit`

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're observing?  How does it indicate that "it doesn't find `edit`"?  Is there an error message on the browser's debugging console?  Some other indication of a problem?  In what specific way does the code shown not work as expected?

Comment: @David I don't know how to pass the row data from table to `edit` as a string, I want when I call edit function, it prints the one of the parameters on the row

Comment: You're currently passing the `item` object in its entirety.  Which seems much more useful than just a string.  What string are you trying to pass to that function?  Currently that function doesn't *do anything* other than log an empty line to the console.  I'm afraid it's very unclear what you're trying to do or what isn't working as expected.  At a glance this code *appears* to successfully pass a row's data object to a function, and then successfully does nothing with that object in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost implemented it, but your edit function was not defined properly.

```
function SampleComponent () {
  // rest of the codes ...

  const addToRoundHandler = (selectedItem) => {
    console.log(selectedItem)   // ---> print your selected item object!
    console.log(`Item name : ${selectedItem.nameEn} and the owner ${selectedItem.owner}`)
    // you might need to call an API to send the selected item to the server
  }

  return (
   // rest of the codes ...

     <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
       <Button 
         variant="primary"
         value={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Publish'}
         onClick={() => addToRoundHandler(item)}  // ---> here
         disabled={loading}
       >
         Add to round
       </Button>
     </TableCell>
  // rest of the codes ...
  )
}
```

Pay attention to the comments on the codes. I use some meaningful names to better explain, you can change them.

if you want to show the selected item on the page, you need to create a state variable:

```
function SampleComponent () {
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState({})

  // rest of the codes ...
  
  const addToRoundHandler = (selectedItem) => {
    console.log(selecteItem);
    setCurrentItem(currentItem)   
  }

  // rest of the codes ...
  
  return (
    // rest of the codes ...
    <div>
     {
       currentItem.length > 0 && <p> You selected: {currentItem.name} </p>
     }
    </div>
    // rest of the codes ...
  )

}
```

Comment: thanks It worked! and I actually didn't know I need th second piece too lol! mercy dadash :D

Comment: it's my please @Matinshoon