# Change the input text file in react

Tags: reactjs

New to React and using a simple table.  I'm just testing to change an input text value when I select a button on the same row.

[image]

The code below is where I'm stuck.  I'm trying to figure out how to change the state value "users" for this row when I click on the button.  I'm trying to set the first_name to "Testing".

```
const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(null);

let usersList =
    businessUsersState.data.length > 0 &&
    businessUsersState.data.map((item: any, key: number) => {
                return (
        <tr key={key} data-account={item.account_id}>
            <td>
                <Form.Control name="first-name" type="input" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={item.first_name} />
            </td>
            <td>
                <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={() => {
            debugger;
            const row = businessUsersState.data.map((item: any) => ({...item}));
            row[key].first_name = 'Testing';
            
            const row1 = usersList[key];

            
            //setUserRow(row);
            //setUsers(row);
        }}>
                </Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
    });

setUsers(usersList);
```

I was reading the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156117/react-js-get-data-from-row-in-rendered-table-to-edit-data) but I cant seem to get it to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Well, that's where I'm stuck.  The value of users is the HTML data. When I set row[key].first_name = 'Testing'; I don't know how to change that rows state to update the data

Comment: I get the error: Cannot create property 'value' on a string 'John' so I tried row[key].first_name = 'Testing'; but it doesn't change the value

Comment: The problem is the state users aren't the simple array that businessUsersState.data contains.  It's the whole table row elements.  So what I'm trying to figure out is how to update that rows state data?

Comment: This is what the users state contains

_owner:null
_store:{validated: false}
$$typeof:Symbol(react.element)
key:'0'
props:{data-account: '81ffdd69-fc50-49f0-8c84-b9ef64cfb046', children: Array(5), key: <accessor>}
ref:null
type:'tr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following React docs [example of object and array in state](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#examples-objects)

```
const uniqueId = () => {
  // always start with a letter (for DOM friendliness)
  let idstr = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 65));
  do {
    const ascicodeChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 65);
    idstr += String.fromCharCode(ascicodeChar);
    idstr += Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
  } while (idstr.length < 8);

  return idstr.toLowerCase();
};

const fakeData = [
  { id: uniqueId(), company: 'abc', contact: 'a@gmail.com', country: 'China' },
  { id: uniqueId(), company: 'def', contact: 'b@gmail.com', country: 'Japan' },
  {
    id: uniqueId(),
    company: 'ghj',
    contact: 'c@gmail.com',
    country: 'Singapore',
  },
  {
    id: uniqueId(),
    company: 'ikl',
    contact: 'd@gmail.com',
    country: 'Indonesia',
  },
  {
    id: uniqueId(),
    company: 'mno',
    contact: 'e@gmail.com',
    country: 'Thailand',
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(fakeData);

  const handleEdit = (id) => {
    setData(
      data.map((t) => {
        // find item matched given id and mutate that item
        if (t.id === id) {
          return {
            id,
            company: `test${id}`,
            contact: `test${id}@gmail.com`,
            country: `test${id}`,
          };
        } else {
          return t;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
        {(() => {
          if (!data.length) {
            return <p>No data available</p>;
          }
          return data.map((i, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i.id}>
                <td>{i.company}</td>
                <td>{i.contact}</td>
                <td>{i.country}</td>
                <td>
                  {/* pass an id of row to edit fnc */}
                  <button onClick={() => handleEdit(i.id)}>edit</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          });
        })()}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could try to do the same above example.